# What is "NIX" on the NASA Technical Reports Server?

Tags: discussion, resources, search

As this question is more about resources to ask/answer questions than actual space exploration, I am asking it on meta.  Feel free to adjust tags as appropriate.

---

The [NASA Technical Reports Server](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/) allows searching from three databases:

> - NASA STI (536297)
> - NACA (14612)
> - NIX (466225)

The first is obviously NASA's own document collection.  The second is NASA's predecessor agency, the [National Advisory Committee on Aeronautics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA).

**What is NIX?**  I usually have it unchecked; does it have any documents that would reasonably help ask or answer a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIX doesn't really exist any more. It was one of the many redundant image sites NASA had, specifically one hosted at Langley. It used to look like this.

[image]

(internet archive [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090130174336/http://nix.nasa.gov/))

Note that the weblink today doesn't go anywhere.

[image]

I haven't tested them all, but results found through checking the NIX option on ntrs generally result in broken links.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The NTRS site currently has a banner that they are improving the search abilities.  Hopefully they will follow through on that.

Comment: Do any of the NIX results have Wayback Machine archive pages? Because it still might be useful in that case.

Comment: @called2voyage no, the backend servers are gone. Internet Archive didn't capture all that stuff.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Hmm, I had a moment to try myself, and the very first search result I got from NIX was in the Internet Archive. They may not have captured all of it, but it may still be useful.

Comment: @called2voyage I searched for 'wind tunnel' and got a 404. YMMV

Comment: I'm getting about a one out of five ratio on hits in the Internet Archive. So there's a lot missing but there's a good amount there.

Comment: You're right about wind tunnel though, the top 10 are all absent from the Internet Archive

Comment: Odd considering it was hosted at Langley ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

According to [NASA itself](https://www.nasa.gov/search/multimedia/index_prt.htm),

> The NASA Image eXchange (NIX) is a web-based search engine for simultaneously searching one or more of NASA's online image and photo collections.

As the saying goes, a picture is worth a thousand words, so they might be helpful (if you can't find an appropriate picture in any other way). But YMMV ...

Comment: YMMV: "written abbreviation for your mileage may vary: used, for example on *social media and in text messages and emails*, to mean that you understand people may have a different opinion or experience to yours" from [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ymmv).

Comment: This information is out of date and incorrect. Note that the NIX link in your reference ends up at ntrs. NASA is very bad at keeping their web sites current.